# 'Infinitivo compuesto' to express actions in the past which did not happen?

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, infinitivo

In my book 'Gramática de uso del Español C1-C2', unit 71 is dedicated to `infinitivo`, and there are two sentences using `infinitivo compuesto`:

> ¿No queréis ir? **Haberlo pensado** antes.
>
> ¿Que estás cansado? **Haber descansado** cuando pudiste antes.

To me, it seems it is used to express something which should have happened/been done in the past, but hasn't. What is this form and where can I read more about it? I tried to search for it but as I don't know the grammatical term, I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not find anything because there is nothing special about those sentences. The two examples you gave are just shortened versions of these two:

> ¿No queréis ir? **Tendríais que haberlo pensado** antes.
>   ¿Que estás cansado? **Tendrías que haber descansado** cuando pudiste antes.

So the sentences are, in fact, using the "tener que + infinitivo" periphrasis, only that the first part is omitted. They use the *infinitivo compuesto* for the reason you talked about in your question: the actions referred are actions that should have been done in the past:

> *Tendríais que pensarlo antes* (you still have time to do so).
>   *Tendríais que haberlo pensado antes* (time to think is over).

That is the purpose of the *infinitivo compuesto*, you can find more about this tense in chapter 26.4 of the *Nueva gramática española: [Los infinitivos verbales. Su interpretación semántica. Infinitivo simple e infinitivo compuesto](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=beQYzzZkcTlYjUrt)* (in Spanish only).

Comment: Though I agree that the semantics are the same, I think the pragmatics are different. The shorter sentences (with no *tener que*) I hear as pointed, even a bit aggressive. The longer sentences can of course be aggressive too, but the short delivery emphasizes that, in my view.

Comment: @walen in fact you have several alternatives: _Deberías haberlo pensado antes_, _Debiste haberlo pensado antes_ or even _Debiste pensarlo antes_ as the "deber" verb is already in a past tense.